# Mockito ClassNotFoundException for Android classes

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to do some unit tests, on fragments and activities that use `SharedPrefrences`, amongst other Android related classes. However, I seem to always get a `ClassNotFound` Exception when I try to mock these like the below:

```
ClassNotFoundException: android.content.Context
```

Here is an example:

My 'TimerFragment' contains a 'MyNotificationManager' class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TimerFragmentUnitTest {

    @Mock
    TimerFragmentView view;
    @Mock
    MyNotificationManger notificationManger;


    private TimerFragmentPresenter presenter;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        presenter = new TimerFragmentPresenter(notificationManger);
        presenter.bindView(view);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendNotification() throws Exception{
        //Given
        doNothing().when(view).setStopEnabled(false);
        doNothing().when(view).setStopEnabled(true);
        //When
        presenter.setMinutesAndSeconds(2000);
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
        //Then
        verify(notificationManger,times(1)).sendTimerFinishNotification();


    }

}
```

In this example, I am getting a `ClassNotFoundException: android.content.Context` error, because `MyNotificationManager` has a `Context` object in it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is an implementation of the `MyNotificationTimer`

```
    public class MyNotificationManger {

        private static final String EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TIMER = "notification_timer";
        private static final int TIMER_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private final Context _context;

        public MyNotificationManger(Context context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void sendTimerFinishNotification() {
            int icon = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP ? R.mipmap.ic_launcher : R.drawable.methodegg;

            Notification.Builder builder =
                    new Notification.Builder(_context)
                            .setSmallIcon(icon)
                            .setContentTitle(_context.getString(R.string.timer))
                            .setContentText(_context.getString(R.string.ready))
                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
                            .setAutoCancel(true);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(_context, NavigationActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TIMER, true);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    _context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(TIMER_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());

        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code for MyNotificationManager. What's the constructor look like? Where's Context used? The error might also be in how the Presenter uses the notification manager in constructing TimerFragmentPresenter

Comment: @JitterbugChew Sure, I have put it up.

Comment: What if you just instantiate `notificationManger` in `setUp()` with a `new MockContext`?

Comment: Unfortunately same error applies,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to find an answer, although Android documentation seems to believe this solution should be used only as a 'last resort'. I put

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

in the top level `build.gradle`.

According to documentation, this should be used if `'If you run a test that calls an API from the Android SDK that you do not mock'`, which I find bizare, as i'm not getting a `'Method ... not mocked'` error, I am getting a `'ClassNotFoundException'`